# Rails select_tag collect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used this code, to collect the names by checking the condition in the model

```
<%=  select_tag "name", options_for_select([["select" , "0" ]] + @names.collect{|p| [p.gatherName(p),p.id]}) %>
```

if condition fails value returns blank, in that case the otpions are ordered like this,

```
  <option value='1'></option> 
  <option value='2'>lamrin</option> 
  <option value='3'></option>
```

while listing the box option 1 is balnk, option 2 has value, and option 3 is blank.

so please help me how to avoid the blank options in the collect

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try select or reject in addition to collect, e.g.

```
<%=  select_tag "name", options_for_select([["select" , "0" ]] + @names.reject{|p|p.gatherName(p).blank?}.collect{|p| [p.gatherName(p),p.id]}) %>
```

I also have to ask why gatherName takes a parameter that is the same as the object it is called on?

Edit: Doh, too slow I see.

Comment: Ahh I forgot about the reliable .blank? :), cleaner solution.

Comment: thanks a lot... actually the real scenario is different here, with similar functionality..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@names.collect{|p| [p.gatherName(p),p.id]}.reject {|i| i.first.blank?}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `p.gatherName(p)` is probably returning nil / ''.

You could do something like this :

```
<%= select_tag "name", options_for_select([["select" , "0" ]] + @names.select {|p| p.gatherName(p) && !p.gatherName(p).empty?}.collect{|p| [p.gatherName(p),p.id]}) %>
```